# Determine how to calculate times across different timezones using nodaTime and withZone on ZoneDateTime

Tags: timezone-offset, nodatime

When converting times between time zones.  I found the follow code works.  However I am not sure how programmatically what to put as my offset for the constructor for the `ZonedDateTime`.  I had a choice of one of the offsets on zoneChicago, which is just two, because its either with our without daylight savings, but how do I know which one I use, and for timezones that have more then just two, what is the best way to populate that offset?

Thanks,

Jim

```
var zoneLA      = c.GetZoneOrNull("America/Los_Angeles");
var zoneChicago = c.GetZoneOrNull("America/Chicago");

var zdtChicago = new ZonedDateTime( LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now)
                                  , zoneChicago
                                  , zoneChicago.MaxOffset);

var zdtLA = zdtChicago.WithZone(zoneLA);
```

Comment: Okay, tried this, not sure if this is correct:  `var zoneLA = c.GetZoneOrNull("America/Los_Angeles");`  `var zoneChicago = c.GetZoneOrNull("America/Chicago");`
`var now = DateTime.Now;`
`var iNow = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(now.ToUniversalTime());`
`var zdtChicago = new ZonedDateTime(LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(now), zoneChicago, zoneChicago.GetZoneInterval(iNow).WallOffset);`
`var zdtLA = zdtChicago.WithZone(zoneLA);`

Comment: Will have a look at this when I get time - soon, I promise! It's probably worth moving your comment into the question for the sake of readability though.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in the current time, you can make this *much* simpler - and indeed more testable. Make your code take an [`IClock`](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.1.x/docs/api/html/T_NodaTime_IClock.htm) as a "service for providing the current instant in time". For the concrete implementation, use [`SystemClock.Instance`](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.1.x/docs/api/html/F_NodaTime_SystemClock_Instance.htm) in production, but `FakeClock` for testing.

`IClock` has a single member: [`Now`](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.1.x/docs/api/html/P_NodaTime_IClock_Now.htm). That returns the current [`Instant`](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.1.x/docs/api/html/T_NodaTime_Instant.htm) in time, which isn't tied to a time zone or even a calendar system.

With an `Instant` and a time zone, you can easily get to a `ZonedDateTime`:

```
Instant now = clock.Now;
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Los_Angeles"];
ZonedDateTime = now.InZone(zone);
```

It will work out what the local date/time and offset is. You don't need to do anything clever :)