# Converting time between different time zones

Tags: c#, windows, datetime, windows-store-apps, nodatime

I am building a windows store clock app to show the current time of the user and also for different cities around the world.

Initially, I had planned on doing this completely using time zone web services from Google etc., but after looking at the number of requests allowed in free accounts and the cost involved in getting a paid account, I felt it was better to find an alternate solution without having to mortgage the house.

Searching around, I found the excellent NodaTime library by John Skeet and team. After digging through the documentation and here on stackoverflow, my head is still buzzing with all the date time and timezone related terminology and conversion methods. Anyway, I thought I could do this with 2 options:

**Option 1**: Using DateTime.Now to get the current system time and then getting time for other zones using nodatime like this (based on code provided by Matt Johnson in reply to another question on SO):

```
DateTimeZone homeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Asia/Colombo"];
LocalDateTime homeTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
ZonedDateTime homeTimeInZone = homeTime.InZoneStrictly(homeZone);
TbTime1.Text = "Home time is: " + homeTimeInZone.ToDateTimeOffset();

DateTimeZone timeZone1 = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Australia/Perth"];
ZonedDateTime timeZone1Time = homeTimeInZone.WithZone(timeZone1);
TbTime2.Text = "Timezone 1 time is: " + timeZone1Time.ToDateTimeOffset();
```

**Option 2**: After looking further, I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575438/determine-how-to-calculate-times-across-different-timezones-using-nodatime-and-w) and felt it would also work nicely like this:

```
public ZonedDateTime GetTimeInTimeZone(string timeZone)
{
    // Timezone is olson timezone e.g. "Asia/Colombo"
    Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.Now;
    var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZone];
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = now.InZone(zone);
    return zonedDateTime;
 }
```

Now let me try to get to the question: In both options above, there is a dependency on either **DateTime.Now** or **SystemClock.Instance.Now** to first identify the user's system time and THEN convert it to the required timezone's city time. But what happens if the user's system is not set to the correct time? I believe (correct me if wrong) DateTime.Now and SystemClock.Instance.Now are both using the system clock to get the current time? Assuming that the system time is not set correctly, then any timezone conversion will simply show the wrong time for other cities due to our dependency on the user's system time.

In such cases, how do I establish the user's current time without relying on their system clock? Should I revert to using a web service to get the user's current time zone using lat/long or is there a better option using NodaTime etc that can work offline? Thanks.

Comment: If the users time is wrong then they probably don't have a requirement for complete accuracy with time (or an invalid copy of windows). You could always compare their time once with a web clock.

Comment: @Sayse Being a clock app, users will expect it to show the correct time even though their system is not setup correctly. I have received enough support requests where this problem exists and hence this question. Comparing with a web clock is one option, but just wondering if there is an alternate way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of points:

- Avoid using `DateTime.Now`

  - It's already translated to the local time zone, so during DST fall-back transitions the result can be ambiguous.
  - If you need to get an exact unambiguous moment in time without using Noda Time, then use `DateTime.UtcNow`.
  - You could also use `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`, or `DateTimeOffset.Now`.  When the offset is included, there is no ambiguity.
  - See also [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/) on my blog.
- In Noda Time, realize that `SystemClock.Instance` is an implementation of the `IClock` interface.  Whenever possible, you should code against the interface, such that you can replace the implementation in your unit tests if desired.  Though in the simplest of examples, there's nothing *wrong* with calling `SystemClock.Instance.Now`, it just isn't as testable.
- As far as which time zone input to use, that is entirely based on your application requirements.

  - If you can depend on the system to be set to the correct zone, you can retrieve it with

    ```
    DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
    ```
  - If you can't depend on the system time zone to be set correctly, you might consider some other source of input.
  - You mentioned GPS coordinates.  If you have that, perhaps from a mobile device, there are solutions for resolving it to a time zone.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824) for some options.  Noda Time can't help you in this regard.
  - You might also consider asking the user of your app to pick a time zone from either a drop-down list or a map.  There are some map-based time zone pickers for HTML/JS [here](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker) and [here](http://timezonepicker.com/).  (I am unsure if they will work in a WinJS based Windows Store App or not, and I don't know of any XAML based solutions off hand.)
- If the actual *time* of their clock is set wrong, there's not a lot you can do, other than try to reach out to another server to retrieve a time stamp. In most cases, you should rely on the operating system to already be synchronized with a time server.

  - If you *do* require synchronization with an external service, that can be challenging.  You need something that implements NTP properly, including measuring and compensating for transmission delay.  That's not easy, and probably requires an external library.  I don't know of one off-hand to recommend.
  - Reaching out to a web service and returning the current time isn't necessarily going to be as accurate as you might think, as that does not compensate for the time it takes for the server to transmit that response to you.
  - If you are running on a device with a GPS receiver, then it is technically possible that it can provide an accurate time stamp received from the GPS signal.  Whether or not that is retrievable and usable via the Windows Store API, I am not sure.  I checked a few references on MSDN but came up empty.
- Regarding the two code samples you provided, they're doing slightly different things, but go with option 2.  It's much cleaner, and is pure Noda Time.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I will go with the solution you suggested (providing timezone dropdowns) and not using web services. Btw, I saw some code you had provided to get a list of timezones based on country code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17098904/537871 - this seems like a good solution to let a user enter his city, select the country from a dropdown and then select the timezone for the selected country.

Comment: need a quick clarification when you say don't use DateTime.Now - is this applicable even when showing the current time in a clock app that is updating every second in a timer? Should DateTimeOffset.Now be used instead?

Comment: If all you are doing is displaying it, and it being called on the device itself, then `DateTime.Now` won't hurt you.  But if you might adjust that to other time zones, or do any math with it, then you should use `DateTimeOffset.Now` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can usually rely on the local time being accurate, as displayed by the clock.  Any Windows machine is setup to talk to a time server, the default is time.windows.com.  The user will notice a discrepancy with the rest of the clocks in his house.  Getting daylight saving transition dates wrong is certainly possible.  But then you don't want to overrule the user's settings, he may well live in a county that's close to the timezone border and opted out of DST or a place that just made up their own rules, like an American Indian tribal area.

Making such decisions about remote places in the world is an entirely different ball of wax.  Notable is the island of Samoa, it hopped across timezones in 2011, even crossing the date line from UTC-11 to UTC+13.  Daylight savings rules are always affected by local political decisions, they don't make the top of the news in your local newspaper.  Some odds that a it does make it to a web service.  Mapping a city to a timezone is in itself something that requires an extensive database.  If absolute accuracy is required then you really do need a service.

Comment: That extensive database you speak of is the [IANA TZDB](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).  It's incorporated into Noda Time, and can be updated as frequently as new TZDB releases come out.  Most of the services out there base their response on this same data, but don't necessarily update as frequently as you might require in your own applications.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Daylight savings is a PITA to handle and hence I was looking at using a web service. Due to costs involved (and also response speed), an offline solution like NodaTime seems ideal for this since it has the database built in.