# Comparing LocalDateTime for Different Time Zones in Nodatime

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, nodatime

I am working on an application that allows a user to schedule an event. The user supplies an Olson time zone by using a [Time Zone Picker](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker), and a date and time for said event through an asp calendar picker and third-party ajax time picker (so the `DateTime` supplied will always be in the same pattern). I compare the time the user wants and the time zone the user supplies with our server's time and its time zone, and fire the event the instant the user expects it to be fired.

From what I understand, having read [this link at the nodatime google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/noda-time/eJzEI8A7Zf0), converting one `ZonedDateTime` to another time zone (using `WithZone`) is fairly straightforward (once I have the user's event mapped from `LocalDateTime` to a `ZonedDateTime`, obviously). I don't need to worry about offsets, and daylight savings time differences between, say, Pheonix and Chicago will be properly accounted for.

I had originally converted the server's time (`DateTime.Now`) to a `ZonedDateTime` and compared this way, but after reading [this link on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575438/determine-how-to-calculate-times-across-different-timezones-using-nodatime-and-w) I switched to using `IClock`.

So far in testing everything is working out, but I am worried about corner cases that I might not be testing for. According to the documentation for NodaTime:

> The biggest "gotcha" is converting `LocalDateTime` to `ZonedDateTime` - it has some corner cases you need to consider.

I have read through the documentation thoroughly and I assume that this gotcha is in reference to those times of the year that either do not occur or that occur twice. These times will never be set as event times for our users but I do use the `LenientResolver` for them. Are there any other gotchas - **when I convert from `LocalDateTime` to `ZonedDateTime`, am I missing anything** or will daylight savings time end up haunting me?

Also, **do I need to convert the user's `ZonedDateTime` to the server time zone before comparison** (which I am doing now) or is this an unnecessary (or even erroneous) step? Will NodaTime be able to compare properly (without daylight savings problems) if I were to compare the event's unconverted `ZonedDateTime` (instead of the event's `ZonedDateTime` after conversion to the server time zone) to the current server `ZonedDateTime` (see code below, third to last line)? When stepping through the code I can see the times and offsets, but I'm worried that doing this might be an oversimplification that introduces problems.

```
Protected Function EventIsReady(ByVal insTimeZone As String, ByVal eventDate As DateTime) As Boolean
        Dim clock As IClock = SystemClock.Instance
        Dim now As Instant = clock.Now

        'server time zone (America/Chicago), unfortunately not UTC
        Dim zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb("America/Chicago")
        Dim serverZonedDateTime = now.InZone(zone)

        'user time zone
        Dim userTimeZone As NodaTime.DateTimeZone = NodaTime.DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull(insTimeZone)
        Dim userEventLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(eventDate)
        Dim eventZonedDateTime = userTimeZone.ResolveLocal(userEventLocalDateTime, Resolvers.LenientResolver)
        Dim eventTimeInServerTimeZone = eventZonedDateTime.WithZone(zone)

        Dim isReady As Boolean = False
        If eventTimeInServerTimeZone >= serverZonedDateTime Then
            isReady = True
        End If
        Return isReady
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're on the right track.

Regarding `LenientResolver`, make sure you are aware of its behavior.  It uses `ReturnStartOfIntervalAfter` for the spring-forward gap, and `ReturnLater` for the fall-back overlap.

IMHO, that isn't the best configuration for scheduling of future events.  (See [Issue #295](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/detail?id=295)), and try this instead:

**VB.NET**

```vb
Public Shared ReadOnly SchedulingResolver As ZoneLocalMappingResolver = _
  Resolvers.CreateMappingResolver(Resolvers.ReturnEarlier, _
  AddressOf ReturnForwardShifted)

Public Shared Function ReturnForwardShifted(local As LocalDateTime, _
  zone As DateTimeZone, before As ZoneInterval, after As ZoneInterval) _
  As ZonedDateTime
    Dim newLocal As LocalDateTime = local.PlusTicks(after.Savings.Ticks)
    Return New ZonedDateTime(newLocal, zone, after.WallOffset)
End Function
```

**C#**

```csharp
public static readonly ZoneLocalMappingResolver SchedulingResolver =
  Resolvers.CreateMappingResolver(Resolvers.ReturnEarlier, ReturnForwardShifted);

public static ZonedDateTime ReturnForwardShifted(LocalDateTime local,
  DateTimeZone zone, ZoneInterval before, ZoneInterval after)
{
    LocalDateTime newLocal = local.PlusTicks(after.Savings.Ticks);
    return new ZonedDateTime(newLocal, zone, after.WallOffset);
}
```

Regarding the server's time zone - you should leave that out of your code.  Your code *should not care* what the time zone of the server is.  Instead, call `ToInstant()` on the `ZonedDateTime` (your `eventZonedDateTime` variable), then compare that with the `Instant` returned from `clock.Now`.

Comment: Note, the lenient resolver has been changed to the above behavior for Noda Time 2.x.  See "Lenient resolver changes" in [the migration guide](http://nodatime.org/unstable/userguide/migration-to-2.html).