# How to set a ZonedDateTime's time component in Nodatime correctly

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime

I have a method that is supposed to return the start time of a working day, e.g. 9AM from a ZonedDateTime that it takes as a parameter:

```
public ZonedDateTime GetWorkStartTime(ZonedDateTime zdt) => (zdt.Zone.AtStartOfDay(zdt.Date).Date + WorkDayStartTime).InZone(zdt.Zone, CommonLenientResolver);
```

`WorkDayStartTime` is a `new LocalTime(9, 0)`

`CommonLenientResolver` is a custom resolver, see the implementation at [Comparing LocalDateTime for Different Time Zones in Nodatime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123884/comparing-localdatetime-for-different-time-zones-in-nodatime/25124701#25124701)

So for any particular zdt, I'd like to be sure that the return value is always the 9AM of the day that the zdt parameter represents.

As stated in AtStartOfDay(...)'s documentation, should the midnight of a day where the clock changes not exist (e.g. the clock moves forward at midnight straight to 1AM), Nodatime will automatically use the next available instance, 1AM.
In my current implementation, I'm adding 9 hours to AtStartOfDay(...), therefore if the start of the day is ever 1AM, my GetWorkStartTime(...) will return 10AM, which is what I'd like to avoid.

I'm using Nodatime 1.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't need to use `AtStartOfDay` at all - just use the date and add your `WorkDayStartTime`:

```
public ZonedDateTime GetWorkStartTime(ZonedDateTime zdt) =>
    (zdt.Date + WorkDayStartTime).InZone(zdt.Zone, CommonLenientResolver);
```

Or if you find it clearer:

```
public ZonedDateTime GetWorkStartTime(ZonedDateTime zdt) =>
    zdt.Date.At(WorkDayStartTime).InZone(zdt.Zone, CommonLenientResolver);
```

Assuming your resolver handles everything the way you want it to for skipped/ambiguous values, that should be fine.