# Convert System.DateTime to NodaTime.ZonedDateTime

Tags: c#, nodatime

I have a `System.DateTime` which is already in a specific timezone but does not specify a `DateTime.Kind`, and a string that represents an IANA timezone. I want to convert this to a `NodaTime.ZonedDateTime`.

For example:

```
var original = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0);
var timezone = "America/Chicago";
```

I want a `ZonedDateTime` that represents 01/01/2016 - 12PM in Chicago time. How do I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to take a standard `DateTime` with a known time in `Chicago` and get a `ZonedDateTime` representing this Date + Time + Time Zone, correct?

If so, I believe this will do it.  The intermediate conversion from `DateTime` to `LocalDateTime` might not be necessary if you can construct it directly.

```
var dotNetDateTime = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0);
var localDate = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dotNetDateTime);
var chicagoTime = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Chicago"];
var chicagoZonedDateTime = chicagoTime.AtStrictly(localDate); // Will contain 2016 01 01 noon

// now you can convert to time in Los Angeles
var laTime = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Los_Angeles"];
var laZonedDateTime = chicagoZonedDateTime.WithZone(laTime); // will contain 2016 01 01 10am
```

Comment: Yes, this is right - but also you might consider that `AtStrictly` may or may not have the behavior you're looking for.  Good to get familiar with the other options such as `AtLeniently`, and custom resolvers such as the [scheduling resolver I show here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25124701/634824), (which is the new lenient resolver in 2.x).